# How to Solve for $x$ in the equation $\sin(2x) = -\frac{1}{2}$ within the interval of $[0, 2\pi]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So far, I only have the solutions $11\pi/12$, and $7\pi/12$ (I think there are a total of $4$). I think this has something to do with trig identities, and should be able to be solved without using a calculator. However, I have only been able to get the above solutions using my calculator.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to solve for X.

Comment: Is there an equation you are trying to solve?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I only put sin(2x); I meant to put sin(2x) = (-1/2).

Comment: Suppose that $\theta = 2x$, and that the Domain for $x$ is $[0,2\pi]$. What would the domain for $\theta$ be?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$\sin(2x) = -\frac{1}{2}$$ then 
\begin{align*}
2x & = \arcsin\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) + 2n\pi & 2x & = \pi - \arcsin\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) + 2m\pi\\
2x & = -\frac{\pi}{6} + 2n\pi & 2x & = \pi - \left(-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) + 2m\pi\\
x & = -\frac{\pi}{12} + n\pi & 2x & = \frac{7\pi}{6} + 2m\pi\\
 & & x & = \frac{7\pi}{12} + m\pi
\end{align*} 
where $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  The requirement that $x \in [0, 2\pi]$ implies $n = 1, 2$ and $m = 0, 1$.

Answer (score 1):

All possible solutions to the general equation $\sin(x)=k$ are of the form 
$x = \arcsin(k) + 2\pi n$ or $x = \pi - \arcsin(k) + 2\pi m$, where $n,m$ are integers.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.